# Use Java streams to perform action on any element only with lambdas

Tags: java, java-stream

I've written this code not for practical purpose but mostly out of curiosity... (btw, I know the title is not great but I couldn't think of something better... suggestions are welcome)

Consider the following:

```
State next = Stream.generate(q::poll).takeWhile(Objects::nonNull)
    .filter(s -> {
        if (atGoal(s)) return true;
        s.expand().forEach(q::add);
        return false;
    }).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Say I wanted to shorten it to use only lambdas... how would I do it?

I managed this, but I was wondering if there's some way to avoid the part with `anyMatch(b -> true)`

```
State goal = Stream.generate(fringe::poll).takeWhile(Objects::nonNull)
    .filter(s -> atGoal(s) || s.expand().map(fringe::add).anyMatch(b -> true))
    .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Comment: Modifying and querying the queue all in one go makes streams really quite awkward.  I  strongly advise just not using streams here.

Comment: Just saying, the first is much more readable and  that I think is good.

Comment: Like I said, I'm mostly just curious.

Comment: if you extract a method, you can use a method reference:   `Stream.generate(fringe::poll).takeWhile(Objects::nonNull)
        .filter(s->myMethodWithSideEffects(s,q))
        .findFirst().orElse(null);`

Comment: Seems like this would violate the [non-interference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference) recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying a traversal algorithm like Breadth first search using Streams (and `q` in your code probably stands for `Queue`).

In this case, replacing a loop with a stream isn't a bright idea because both of the versions of the code you've provided are broken.

Here's a couple quotes from the Stream API documentation.

[**Non-interference**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Non-interference):

> Accordingly, behavioral parameters in stream pipelines whose source
> might not be concurrent **should never modify the stream's data
> source**. A behavioral parameter is said to interfere with a
> non-concurrent data source if it modifies, or causes to be modified,
> the stream's data source. The **need for non-interference applies to
> all pipelines**, not just parallel ones. **Unless** the stream
> **source is concurrent**, modifying a stream's data source during execution of a stream pipeline can cause exceptions, incorrect
> answers, or nonconformant behavior.

So if the stream source `q` is not concurrent, the code is broken. Let's move further.

[**Side-effects**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects)

> If the behavioral parameters do have side-effects, unless explicitly
> stated, there are no guarantees as to:
>
> - the **visibility** of those **side-effects to other threads**;
> - that different operations on the "same" element within the same stream pipeline are executed in the same thread; and
> - that **behavioral parameters are always invoked**, since a **stream implementation is free to elide operations** (or entire stages) from a
>   stream pipeline if it can prove that it would not affect the result of
>   the computation.

A quote from the Javadoc of [`Stream.filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate))

> **Parameters:**
>
> `predicate` - a **non-interfering**, **stateless** predicate to apply to each
> element to determine if it should be included

So you're using a `Predicate` of the `filter` to performs side-effects and interfere with the source of data. Which is discouraged by the documentation. There's no intermediate operations in the API which were designed for such purposes. By their nature intermediate operations are lazy and in certain circumstances can be optimized away. For that reason side-effects you really need to be executed should not be incorporated into an intermediate operation. This is especially true for `peek()` mentioned in another answer, which according to documentation was designed exclusively to support debugging and can be thrown out from the pipeline because it isn't meant to perform resulting action as opposed to the terminal operations `forEach()` and `forEachOrdered()`, which also should be used with caution (and they would not help in implementing BFS).

That said, there's no correct and clean way to achieve what you want using Streams.

Comment: The `q` is indeed a queue (a priority queue to be exact). The code is single threaded. I think the best argument (considering that it is single threaded) is this part: "that behavioral parameters are always invoked, since a stream implementation is free to elide operations (or entire stages) from a stream pipeline if it can prove that it would not affect the result of the computation.". Thanks.